# JqGrid colModel dynamic formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

My `jqGrid` work dynamically.So that all options are loaded dynamically too.
This options are generated with java `Map<String,Object>`
All options work very well, but the function name within de `map/opts` not work.
This is `json` map generated with java.

```
"colModel":[...{"formatter":"myFunction","index":"","name":""}]
```

I did not debug the `jqgrid.src.js` yet and i think that the problem are with the `eval`.
the "myFunction" is not called and the undefined is returned.

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow, but if you are having problems with the formatter you should be able to just define it as `"formatter":myFunction` and then `myFunction` will be called when the grid needs to format that column. But you mention `eval`... is something else going on here?

Comment: The opts are in HashMap<String,Object>.
Map<String, Object> opts = new HashMap<String, Object>();
opts.put("formatter","myFunction");
opts.put("index","");
opts.put("name","");

Then, the opts formatter for the colModel ouptup:
{"formatter":"myFunction","index":"","name":""}

Comment: this is the function on js file.
function myFunction(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
 return "<a href='/myapps/crud/editSomething?id="+ options.rowId + "'>Click here</a>";
}

I do not why the jqGrid no call the myFunction?
With i get the opts that a show above and put on the reall file it work;
Here work
colModel:[
 ...
 {"formatter":myFunction,"index":"","name":""}
 //work 
],
Here not work
colModel:[
 ...
 {"formatter":"myFunction","index":"","name":""}
 // pay attention: the myFunction with string in the real file no work too. 
],

Comment: Well, all the options in the jqGrid work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `formatter` option can be a string if it is one of the predefined formatters, but according to the [jqGrid docs for custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter):

> You can define your own formatter for a particular column. Usually this is a function.

So jqGrid expects a function to be passed. This is why `myFunction` works but `"myFunction"` does not. Anyway, to solve your problem you need to output the code:

```
"formatter": myFunction
```

---

To go a bit deeper, you can see in the jqGrid source file [grid.base.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js) that the formatter uses a function directly, but if a string is passed that string is passed to `$.fn.fmatter`:

```
    formatter = function (rowId, cellval , colpos, rwdat, _act){
        var cm = ts.p.colModel[colpos],v;
        if(typeof cm.formatter !== 'undefined') {
            var opts= {rowId: rowId, colModel:cm, gid:ts.p.id, pos:colpos };
            if($.isFunction( cm.formatter ) ) {
                v = cm.formatter.call(ts,cellval,opts,rwdat,_act);
            } else if($.fmatter){
                v = $.fn.fmatter(cm.formatter, cellval,opts, rwdat, _act);
            } else {
                v = cellVal(cellval);
            }
        } else {
            v = cellVal(cellval);
        }
        return v;
    },
```

If that function is not already present in [jquery.fmatter.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/jquery.fmatter.js) then I would expect an error to occur when the grid attempts to use it.

Comment: Yes, man.
To use function enclosed in quotes we can formatter module so that it can be easy extended.
More detail about Creating common formatter function